# Twilio Warning - 12200 Schema validation warning while I'm using calling feature

Tags: twilio, incoming-call

I am getting this error from Twilio.

```
<Response>
  if params["DialCallStatus"] == "completed" or params["DialCallStatus"] == "answered"
<Hangup/>
  else
<Say voice="man">
  The call could not be answered this time, please leave a message
</Say>
<Record action="/Record_Complete"/>
  end
</Response>
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: @m_callens 
Still Facing the same error.

Comment: i didn't answer/solve your question...I only reformated the text to be readable

Comment: No Problem m_callens....

Comment: What language are you writing the code to return this TwiML in?

Comment: @philnash 
I'm using visualforce and page but that for the reply I got the solution but I have more questions can I have your email where i can ask more questions?

Comment: Sure, you can get me at philnash@twilio.com. I'm not so hot on building on Salesforce, but I can help with Twilio questions. :)

Comment: @philnash Thanks a lot, man :)